# Two circles intersect of radii $1$m

Tags: geometry

There are two circles of radii $1$m. They intersect such that the circumference of one passes through the center of the other. Find the area enclosed between the 2 circles.

I tried this using the area of an ellipse, but my answer was not right. I thought one taking axis as $1$m and calculating the other using the Pythagoras theorem, but my answer seems to be incorrect. Please help.

Comment: Find the area of which "shaded region"? You did not include a diagram.

Comment: I think where the circles intersect

Comment: Common region b/w them

Comment: Please show us your work so we can point out your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of ellipse will not work, as the intersected area will not be an ellipse

---

Let me show you how will you find the area.

[image: IMG 1]

area of $ABCD$ will be $2\cdot$ [area of segment($ABD$)] (symmetry)

Area of segment $ABD=\frac12\times r^2\times[\left(\frac\pi{180}\right)\theta-\sin\theta]$

---

Now to find the angle we apply some trigonometry

as $EC=1/2 \to$ [half of ac which is 1(radius)]

and $BC =1 \to$ (RADIUS)

thus $\cos(BCE)=EC/BC=1/2=\cos 60$

Thus angle $BCE = 60^\circ$

and angle $BCD = 120^\circ$

---

NOW WE ARE DONE WITH ANGLE

NOW PUTTING IT IN FORMULA

Area of segment $ABD$=$\frac12\times r^2\times[\left(\frac\pi{180}\right)\theta-\sin\theta]$
=$\frac12\times r^2\times[\left(\frac\pi{180}\right)120^\circ-\sin 120^\circ]$

area of required $ABCD$= $2\times\frac12\times r^2\times[\left(\frac\pi{180}\right)120^\circ-\sin 120^\circ]$

=$\frac{2\pi}3-\frac{\sqrt 3}2$

PLEASE CONFIRM IF IT IS CORRECT

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: AHH okay but it take time

but from now i will try using latex

Comment: Thanks @ACB for editing it

Comment: It is right answer